# Updating app that were downloaded with a different apple ID

Tags: apple-id

I got my dad's old phone and had previously downloaded certain apps. Redownloading these apps was not an issue but when the apps needed updates, it needed me to input my dad's Apple ID password for all the redownloaded apps. How do I transfer these apps to my AppleID?

If I can get advise for this or info that there is no real solution, that would be very helpful.

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Are you asking how to avoid the prompt, about how to transfer the apps to your account, about recovering your dad‘s password, or something else?

Comment: I am mainly seeking how to transfer the app to my account

Comment: If you know your dad‘s Passwort you can just enter it for updates.

Answer (score 2):

Apps and other digital content are *non-transferable* between Apple IDs. This has been a sticking point for many users in the past, since you can't even transfer between the same Apple ID but between different regions. There are two potential solutions:

1. Abandon the apps on your dad's account. Re-buy them on your new Apple ID.
2. Use your dad's Apple ID for iTunes stores purchases only, and your own for everything else. You can do this by Settings > iTunes & App Stores and changing your Apple ID there to your dad's Apple ID, but still logging into your own for iCloud. I know that this is how a few of my friends share their apps in their families.

Answer (score 1):

As @SolarMike has suggested in his answer, you may want to do a Factory Reset of the phone before you invest too much time and effort setting it up. A Factory Reset will avoid potential conflicts between apps or services installed or configured previously. But since you didn't ask, I'll assume you're happy to simply change the Apple ID. You may not have any issues at all; if you do, here's a link explaining how to do a [Factory Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252). Note that you can perform the Factory Reset with or without your Dad's Apple ID & password.

And now, the answer to the question you asked: Note that this procedure will vary somewhat depending upon which iPhone you have. The following is for an iPhone 6, but other models will be similar.

You may change the Apple ID as follows:

#### 1. Logout from the current Apple ID:

- Open/tap `Settings` app, and select **`iTunes & App Store`**
- Tap the line near the top: **`Apple ID: email@address.com`**
- In the `Apple ID` pop-up window, tap the option **`Sign Out`**

Once you've logged out, the Apple ID sign-in screen should be blank/empty.

#### 2. Login with your Apple ID (or create a new Apple ID)

- Tap the **`Sign In`** line where the old Apple ID was formerly located
- Enter your Apple ID and Password in the pop-up window, then tap **`Sign In`**

You should see the "spinning wheel" briefly, and then your Apple ID email will appear in the line near the top.

You're done.